# Buildroot is ignoring my package when building image

Tags: c, linux, makefile, buildroot

I am attempting to build a custom application through buildroot but everytime I run 'make' from the base directory, it completely ignores and doesnt build my application in. As far as im aware I have included the correct files and referenced my application in the .in files, and I can select it on makemenuconfig. I am also able to run 'make' from within the package directory and it builds the .o file correctly. I also piped the terminal output to a log file, and there is no trace of my package anywhere within

I tried to build a custom buildroot application but the final image does not include my application, even though I can select it within makemenuconfig and it has no trace on the output log.

Comment: You will need to provide more info for us to debug, E.G. how does the Config.in and .mk file look for your custom package and is the option enabled in your .config

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.